# Why do I have to re-pair my Apple Magic Wireless Keyboard (A1314) every morning?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth

I take my laptop home every night. When I come into the office I have to remove the keyboard from the BT devices and re-pair it - otherwise it won't connect. My Apple Magic Trackpad (A1339) connects automatically.

This has only started happening recently. It is consistent and I have to go through the re-pair process every morning. (I have tried replacing the batteries)

Is it a BT issue or a hardware issue? What's the best way to debug this?

Connecting to a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2017) running macOS High Sierra v10.13.6

Comment: @abc - yep - you have to turn it on and off to re-pair it

Comment: When you leave the office, do you turn it off?

Comment: yes. I've turned it on and off plenty of times. Usual process -> click connect on BT menu (doesn't work) -> turn off -> turn on -> click connect again (doesn't work) -> turn off -> hold down on button to enter pairing mode, meanwhile remove device from BT list and click connect as the light starts flashing -> enter pairing code

Comment: Oh. The reason I was asking is if you had left the keyboard on overnight, it could have looked for your MacBook, not found it, and went into some kind of "sleep" state and refused to look for the Mac anymore, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Could the keyboard have connected to anything else in the office by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was caused by an old machine (MacBook Air 2012) in the office that used to be paired with keyboard. The person using the old machine would arrive into the office earlier than me so by the time I had arrived the keyboard had connected to their machine.

Solved by removing the device from the bluetooth devices of the old machine.